# How ubuntu awk get last user and time data?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, awk

my `last` data infomation like :

```
test@test:~$ last
test     pts/0        172.25.48.1      Mon Sep 14 08:38   still logged in
test     pts/2        172.25.48.1      Mon Sep 14 03:32   still logged in
test     pts/1        172.25.48.1      Mon Sep 14 03:31   still logged in
test     pts/1        172.25.48.1      Mon Sep 14 03:22 - 03:31  (00:08)
test     pts/0        172.25.48.1      Mon Sep 14 03:00 - 03:39  (00:39)
test     pts/0        172.25.48.1      Mon Sep 14 02:11 - 02:50  (00:38)
test     pts/0        172.20.80.1      Sun Sep 13 11:34 - 17:02  (05:27)
test     pts/0        172.20.80.1      Sun Sep 13 11:33 - 11:33  (00:00)
test     tty1                          Sun Sep 13 10:53    gone - no logout
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-47-generic Sun Sep 13 10:53   still running
test     pts/1        172.20.80.1      Wed Sep  9 08:39 - 11:52 (2+03:12)
test     pts/0        172.20.80.1      Wed Sep  9 07:04 - 08:45  (01:40)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-47-generic Wed Sep  9 03:06   still running
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-47-generic Wed Sep  9 03:04   still running
test     tty1                          Wed Sep  9 03:03 - crash  (00:00)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-47-generic Wed Sep  9 03:03   still running
test     pts/0        172.20.80.1      Wed Sep  9 03:02 - crash  (00:01)
test     tty1                          Wed Sep  9 02:51 - crash  (00:12)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-47-generic Wed Sep  9 02:50   still running
```

Expected : I'd like to get information like :

```
test     Mon Sep 14 08:38
test     Mon Sep 14 03:32
test     Mon Sep 14 03:31
test     Mon Sep 14 03:22
test     Mon Sep 14 03:00
test     Mon Sep 14 02:11
test     Sun Sep 13 11:34
test     Sun Sep 13 11:33
test     Sun Sep 13 10:53
reboot   Sun Sep 13 10:53
test     Wed Sep  9 08:39
test     Wed Sep  9 07:04
reboot   Wed Sep  9 03:06
reboot   Wed Sep  9 03:04
test     Wed Sep  9 03:03
reboot   Wed Sep  9 03:03
test     Wed Sep  9 03:02
test     Wed Sep  9 02:51
reboot   Wed Sep  9 02:50
```

[image: xxx]

Actually : But I tried to command`last | awk '{print $1"\t"$4}'`,system return data like :

```
test@test:~$ last | awk '{print $1"\t"$4}'
test    Mon
test    Mon
test    Mon
test    Mon
test    Mon
test    Mon
test    Sun
test    Sun
test    Sep
reboot  5.4.0-47-generic
test    Wed
test    Wed
reboot  5.4.0-47-generic
reboot  5.4.0-47-generic
test    Sep
reboot  5.4.0-47-generic
test    Wed
test    Sep
reboot  5.4.0-47-generic
    
wtmp    Sep
```

[image: xxx]

---

updated

I tried `last --time-format iso | awk '{print $1"\t"$4}'` but some of data wrong.

```
test@test:~$ last --time-format iso | awk '{print $1"\t"$4}'
test    2020-09-14T08:38:15+00:00
test    2020-09-14T03:32:02+00:00
test    2020-09-14T03:31:33+00:00
test    2020-09-14T03:22:37+00:00
test    2020-09-14T03:00:05+00:00
test    2020-09-14T02:11:39+00:00
test    2020-09-13T11:34:43+00:00
test    2020-09-13T11:33:36+00:00
test    gone
reboot  5.4.0-47-generic
test    2020-09-09T08:39:02+00:00
test    2020-09-09T07:04:41+00:00
reboot  5.4.0-47-generic
reboot  5.4.0-47-generic
test    -
reboot  5.4.0-47-generic
test    2020-09-09T03:02:08+00:00
test    -
reboot  5.4.0-47-generic
```

Comment: The "automatic" column variables `$1`, `$2`, etc. are based on *any* space. That means something like `system boot` is considered two columns. And the date-strings themselves are four separate columns.

Comment: If your columns are fixed width, use substrings instead of field positions. Basically `cut -c1-9,32-48` though those offsets are almost certainly wrong. WIthout actual data to test on, it's going to be a lot of effort to figure out the precise indices.

Comment: Are you aware that `last` also has options? Like `last --time-format iso` would make filtering trivial and dates exact?

Comment: `cut -c1-9,40-56` seems to work with the data you posted.

Comment: @KamilCuk it's no options

Comment: Then you are not on Ubuntu. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/last.1.html

Comment: @tripleee sorry , I misunderstand your meaning, yes,it has option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested in GNU `awk`. 1st one considers that O.S user names will not have spaces in their names, so I am directly printing $1 in spite of using regex here.

```
last | 
awk '
{
  match($0,/[a-zA-Z]{3} +[a-zA-Z]{3} +[0-9]{1,2} +[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/)
  print $1,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}'
```

OR(following one uses regex to match till `pts` where there could be any other value then `pts` in 2nd column of `last` command in that case above 1st command will be better choice to use.

```
last | 
awk '
match($0,/.*pts/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/ +pts/,"",val)
  match($0,/[a-zA-Z]{3} +[a-zA-Z]{3} +[0-9]{1,2} +[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/)
  print val,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  val=""
}'
```

In case you need output into nice looking alignment then pipe your `awk` command output to `column -t` command.

Comment: wow , it work ! [image](https://ithelp.ithome.com.tw/upload/images/20200915/20129008RbogvOORfZ.png)

Answer (score 3):

If your output is fixed-width fields as it appears in your example and you have GNU awk then:

```
$ cat file | awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='9 30 16' '{print $1 $3}'
test     Mon Sep 14 08:38
test     Mon Sep 14 03:32
test     Mon Sep 14 03:31
test     Mon Sep 14 03:22
test     Mon Sep 14 03:00
test     Mon Sep 14 02:11
test     Sun Sep 13 11:34
test     Sun Sep 13 11:33
test     Sun Sep 13 10:53
reboot   Sun Sep 13 10:53
test     Wed Sep  9 08:39
test     Wed Sep  9 07:04
reboot   Wed Sep  9 03:06
reboot   Wed Sep  9 03:04
test     Wed Sep  9 03:03
reboot   Wed Sep  9 03:03
test     Wed Sep  9 03:02
test     Wed Sep  9 02:51
reboot   Wed Sep  9 02:50
```

In the above I'm using `cat file` in place of `last` which I don't have.

Comment: so simple and clear ![image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2hE7.png)